# Facebook custom page tab not allowed anymore?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

So our app has stopped working recently. Our "installation" process tries to create a custom page tab, which has been working since at least june of last year. Now when one of our customers attempts to start using our app, they get the "Add Page Tab" dialog, select the page wherein they want to install the app, click the "Add Page Tab" button, and instead of working, this error comes up:

"This page does not have permission to install the custom tab."

We are using the latest version of the php API. This successfully works installing the test version of our app on my own Facebook account... I am at a loss. Any suggestions?

Comment: So I got some information back from a Facebook developer, it seems that the rules changed recently so that you can't create a "custom tab" on a Page unless that page has 2000 or more fans. Our app runs as a Canvas iframe into a stripped-down version of our web page. Since they have taken this away, have to figure out what we can come back with.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs: _“The Page Tabs feature is only available to Pages with 2000 or more fans, or pages managed by whitelisted apps.”_

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the deal is, Facebook took away something that was moderately useful - being able to install a Canvas (iframed-in webpage) app on a "Page" accessed via a "Page Tab", and doesn't seem to have any replacement for it. So far, anyway, our customers who have already installed our app will get to keep it, but nobody new can add it.